# Fall asleep suddenly

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, idiom-request

I want to know the informal of saying that a person fell suddenly asleep because he had a very hard day or because he was exhausted or very tired.

For instance a person was reading a book and didn't notice how he fell asleep still holding the book. Or for instance a person was watching a film while sitting and suddenly fell asleep in his sitting pose.

Comment: *Dropped off* is fairly common.

Comment: @StoneyB Something like **He dropped off while reading** and **He dropped off while watching the film**?

Comment: Yeah, perzackly.

Comment: If it isn't in the middle of an activity like reading or watching TV, we can express the idea of falling asleep immediately so: "I was so tired, when my head hit the pillow I was **out like a light**."

Comment: *Informal* or *slang*?

Comment: @Andrew isn't slang informal?

Comment: @SovereignSun  I would say slang is a subset of *informal* speech.  Slang is usually common among a particular group or dialect, while informal speech is more universal.

Comment: @Andrew Right, a subset, okay.

Comment: @SovereignSun  Right, so I was just trying to clarify whether you were looking for *general* expressions you can use anywhere, or some slang expressions which might not be understood by every English speaker.  Or both.   For example a common expression in California (and other parts of the US) is "to crash", but I don't know if this would be understood everywhere else.

Comment: @Andrew General expression. I would want to use in speech and writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for something very informal, but in Washington state (as far as I know) we say:

> "He **conked out**"

"To conk out" means that he fell asleep very suddenly, most likely to exhaustion or strain. "Zonking out" means the same thing, but is generally used more when the person has passed out due to inebriation and the like.

> "He **dropped off**"
>
> "He **crashed**"
>
> "He was **out**" (emphasizing the 'out')

These are also common, but "crashed" implies that he had been being very energetic for some time beforehand.

Comment: What about just *pass out* or *nod off* (I think the latter emphasizes unintentionality or suddenness, but still)? [*Flake out*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flake%20out) looks like a good candidate, too, but I don't know if that slang term is still current (it looks kinda generic so I think it is): "to be overcome especially by exhaustion".

Comment: @userr2684291 I considered it, but I thought that "passing out" might get confusing because that could be used if the person was being asphyxiated, drunk, etc., and the question-asker specifically said the person in question was just tired. I also felt that "nodding off" lacked immediacy.

Comment: The "nodding" in "nodding off" can refer to the multiple time the head can "nod" as the person drifts in and out of sleep, like the person in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qv6xdOFDTP0

This can potentially take a long time

Comment: Definitely, "to crash" is very common out here in the Western United States, and means *exactly* what OP asks.